# Correct way to handle locking of classes shared across threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have cleaned and shortened a snippet of my code for a multiuser game to show what I would like to accomplish. So here it is:

```
    public class Subject {
        public List<IObject> Objects = new List<IObject>();
    }

    public interface IOpenable
    {
        void Open(Subject by, params string[] p);
        void Close(Subject by, params string[] p);
        bool IsOpen { get; }
    }

    public interface IObject {
        void Pickup(Subject by, params string[] p);
        void Drop(Subject by, params string[] p);
    }

    public class Box : IObject, IOpenable
    {
        bool opened = false;
        Subject owner = null;

        public void Pickup(Subject subject, params string[] p) {
            subject.Objects.Add(this);
            this.owner = subject;
        }

        public void Drop(Subject subject, params string[] p)
        {
            subject.Objects.Remove(this);
            this.owner = null;
        }

        public void Open(Subject by, params string[] p)
        {
            this.opened = true;
        }

        public void Close(Subject by, params string[] p)
        {
            this.opened = false;
        }

        public bool IsOpen { get { return opened; } }
    }
```

What I would like to know is:
How to prevent some user (executing code from another thread) to open a Box that is currently being Picked up by some other user.
I've thought of some ways but I think that people here often come up with clever ideas, that could make me avoid some stupid design issue.

EDIT: As suggested in the answers, to use the lock keyword in the open method: this is not exactly what I want, I'll try to explain with what is allowed and what not:

The network requests we get as input are somehow async and get out of order if issued fast.

- (1) User 1 issues command PICKUP BOX
- (2) User 1 issues command OPEN BOX
- (3) User 1 issues command CLOSE BOX
- (4) User 2 issues command OPEN BOX
- (5) User 2 issues command LOOK BOX
- (6) User 1 issues command OPEN BOX

We get this order:

2,3,1,5,4,6

```
2 - allow
3 - allow
1 - allow [remains in execution and has not set the owner]
5(comes in between 1) - allow
4(comes in between 1) - disallow (not because already open but because 1 is in execution)
6(comes in between 1) - allow since it is from user 1, and he is currently picking it up
```

Thanks!

Comment: The solution I posted will satisfy your new conditions - TryOpen() will return false when (3) executes.  You can apply the same approach to the other methods satisfy further conditions if required.

Comment: in tcp the sequence of messages is guarenteed as far as i know, so the worst that could happen is 1,3,4,2 - this you have to handle in your code, meaning remember who 'owns' which object

Comment: as far as i have seen sometimes commands get out of sync if they are issued very fast, seems like there is a connection for each command not one connection, however not my part of code to fiddle with, i'm not an expert... :/

Comment: @Greg could you please post a sample what should the content of the Pickup and Open method be ? PS I added a close in between and i now think the tryopen will pass, and should not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution to this is:

```
Monitor.TryEnter(obj)
```

Similar to lock but not blocking.

So we lock an object when a user start picking it up,

and when Opening the box do a check that says:

```
if (this.subject == subject || Monitor.TryEnter(obj))
```

Comment: that was a result of wrong editing I think. It did not make any sense.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [lock statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to prevent two threads from accessing Open and Close.  To prevent a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) on checking if the box is already opened, we can change `Open()` to `TryOpen()`, and return false if the box is already open.  There are ways to do this so that we don't have to return a boolean, but this is probably the simplest.

If one thread reaches the lock statement while another thread is already inside a lock statement, the second thread will wait until the first thread exits the lock statement before continuing.

```
private object locker=new object();
public bool TryOpen(Subject by, params string[] p)
{
    lock(locker)
    {
        if(this.opened)
            return false;
        this.opened = true;
        return true;
    }
}

public void Close(Subject by, params string[] p)
{   
    lock(locker)
    {
        this.opened = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know of the lock statement, and btw it's not to prevent from concurrent opening of closing but prevent opening a box that is being picked up by another user. However I think I have not clarified myself well. I'll edit the post to reflect this.

Comment: You keep changing the rules! :) I'm not going to change my answer because you might add new rules - it should be easy enough to follow the logic I've shown you to make it work for your specific case.

Comment: ok i think i now have explained well what i'm trying to accomplish, sorry for the confusion. now with the all 6 rules it is complete.

Comment: it is not easy to explain well what i want to accomplish, and english is not my language... but i gave you a like for you effort however :)